# Django sorl placeholder default avatar image

Tags: django, django-models, sorl-thumbnail

I have a project in django using sorl-thumbnail to generate thumbnails. I want to make it so that if a user profile doesnt have an avatar image added yet, it will show a default photo.

I tried doing this in my UserProfile model but I had problems uploading a new image when the default was present

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='blah', default='path/to/my/default/image.jpg')
```

I understand that I could use if statements in all my templates, but this would be repeating myself everywhere. Such as

```
{% ifequal object.avatar None %}
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMAGE" />
{% else %}
    display image
{% endifequal %}
```

What is best practice to show a default image when one doesnt exist already in django?

Comment: sorl-thumbnail has an `{% empty %}` template tag you can use in case there is no image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gabriel mention, you can use the empty tag.

```
{% thumbnail object.avatar "100x100" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% empty %}
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMAGE">
{% endthumbnail %}
```